# jq select() and sort_by()

Tags: json, api, curl, jq

I am parsing a curl output from gitlab api, and I need to add a sort_by to my query, then select only certain values.

sample input:

```
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "another-test",
    "path": "another-test",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "web_url": "https://mygitlab/groups/another-test",
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "full_name": "another-test",
    "full_path": "another-test",
    "parent_id": 9
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "asdfg",
    "path": "asdfg",
    "description": "",
    "visibility": "private",
    "lfs_enabled": true,
    "avatar_url": null,
    "web_url": "https://mygitlab/groups/asdfg",
    "request_access_enabled": false,
    "full_name": "asdfg",
    "full_path": "asdfg",
    "parent_id": 7
  }
```

I parse the JSON with jq as follows:

```
curl http://..... | jq -r '.[] | select(.parent_id!=null) | .name, .parent_id'
```

This works exactly as expected, but when I try to sort the results by parent_id, I get an error:

```
curl http://..... | jq -r '.[] | select(.parent_id!=null) | .name, .parent_id | sort_by(.parent_id)'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index number with string "parent_id"
```

I can use sort_by(), by putting a single dot instead than .[]:

```
curl http://..... | jq '. | sort_by(.parent_id) '
```

But I cannot combine the 2 functions.

Clarification: I need to extract name and parent_id, sorted by parent_id, when it is not null.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**`jq`**'s `sort_by()` function accepts an array as input.

```
curl 'http://...' |
    jq -r '
        map(select(.parent_id != null)) 
        | sort_by(.parent_id)[]
        | [.name, .parent_id]
        | @tsv
    '
```

Sample output:

```
asdfg   7
another-test    9
```

Comment: Great! What is @tsv for? and how can I get one value per line? (no numbers and names on the same line)

Comment: @Bruno9779, welcome, `@tsv` will transform an array of values into string of `tab`-separated items. Each input array will be printed as a single line. You may print "one value per line" with just `| .name, .parent_id` (just as you did before)

Comment: Wish I could give @RomanPerekhrest 100 pts for `@tsv`. Pipe the whole command through `column -t` for improved tabular output on a terminal